# How to generate values in a range continuously?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Dataset` which I need to modify using pandas. Below is the detail of the particular column I need to work on:

```
df["Dependents"].value_counts()

0     345

1     102

2     101

3+     51

Name: Dependents, dtype: int64

df["Dependents"].notnull().value_counts()

True     599

False     15

Name: Dependents, dtype: int64
```

I need to assign the `null` values as `0`, `1` or `2` one by one. Like if for first row, I assign `0`, then next row should be `1` and then the next `2`. Then again start from `0` until all `null` values are filled.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [214]: df
Out[214]:
   Dependents
0         NaN
1           0
2           0
3           0
4         NaN
5           1
6         NaN
7          3+
8         NaN
9          3+
10          2
11         3+
12          1
13        NaN
```

Solution:

```
In [215]: idx = df.index[df.Dependents.isnull()]

In [216]: idx
Out[216]: Int64Index([0, 4, 6, 8, 13], dtype='int64')

In [217]: df.loc[idx, 'Dependents'] = np.take(list('012'), [x%3 for x in range(len(idx))])

In [218]: df
Out[218]:
   Dependents
0           0
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           1
5           1
6           2
7          3+
8           0
9          3+
10          2
11         3+
12          1
13          1
```

Comment: I think OP has column with `null` and numbers  and OP wants to replace only `null` values with 0,1,2 in this column.

Comment: Yes. I have to replace only the null values present in this column.

Comment: @furas, thank you! I didn't notice it first. I've corrected my answer

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks a lot for the answer. This solution works perfectly fine for the scenario. I think this will be helpful in modelling in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to MaxU's answer, but using numpy put with 'wrap' mode.

```
Sample dataframe (df):

    Dependents
0   NaN      
1   0        
2   0        
3   0        
4   NaN      
5   1        
6   NaN      
7   3+       
8   NaN      
9   3+       
10  2        
11  3+       
12  1        
13  NaN  

idx = df.index[df.Dependents.isnull()]
np.put(df.Dependents, idx, [0, 1, 2], mode='wrap')

   Dependents
0   0        
1   0        
2   0        
3   0        
4   1        
5   1        
6   2        
7   3+       
8   0        
9   3+       
10  2        
11  3+       
12  1        
13  1
```

Comment: Nice solution! I never used `np.put()` before